# How can I put my publications into Scopus?

Tags: scopus

I've got many papers which are not on Scopus, but are picked up by Google Scholar. How do I include all those other papers into Scopus?

Answer (score 12):

Scopus uses its own sources for publications in the form of publisher provided content. Their selection procedure is explained here: https://www.elsevier.com/solutions/scopus/content/content-policy-and-selection

There is no procedure to add individual documents to Scopus that I could find on their help pages. You should also be aware that it can take several weeks for a published paper to end up in Scopus. Some publishers (smaller publishers typically or new open-access publishers), conferences, technical reports might never make it to Scopus though.

On a related note, the citation count will probably lag behind Google Scholar.

Comment: "Some publishers (smaller publishers typically or new open-access publishers) ... never make it to Scopus though."

That isn't a correct impression. It's not just smaller publishers or new OA publishers who's journals do not get selected for indexing in Scopus. Hundreds of Elsevier (a large publisher) journals are not even indexed in Scopus, and Scopus is owned and run by Elsevier(RELX Group)! Choice of what gets indexed in Scopus is quite arbitrary. Some say it is a 'quality' filter, but in my opinion the binary of IN or OUT is very harsh on some journals which are left 'OUT' of Scopus.

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you don't understand what Scopus is. Scopus is a database of quality-curated journals and the articles published in those journals. It isn't meant to be comprehensive, and because it's quality-curated, it doesn't mean that all your papers will automatically end up in the database. Comparatively Google Scholar goes for comprehensiveness. It doesn't have a quality bar, and it'll index literally everything and anything. You should be able to find all your papers in Google Scholar, but not in Scopus.

To get your publications into Scopus, publish in a journal that's indexed by Scopus. It's as simple as that. If you've already published elsewhere, it's too late (unless the journal becomes indexed by Scopus).